# Why does my Qt program keeps running after assertion failure?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am developing a Qt application and I am very puzzled about Qt's behavior towards assertion failure. Indeed, I noticed that, although an assertion failure occurs, my program keeps running for some time...

Consider the following code :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow() : crash(false)
    {
        QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
        openAct = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
        connect(openAct, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::open);
        fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
        fileMenu->addAction(openAct);
    }
private slots :
    void        open()
    {
        statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Invoked: File|Open"));
        crash = true;
        assert(false);          // 1st assertion failure ; paintEvent() will be called once more anyway
    }
private:
    void        paintEvent(QPaintEvent* evt) final
    {
        assert(!crash);         // 2nd assertion failure ; execution stops here
        QMainWindow::paintEvent(evt);
    }

    QMenu*      fileMenu;
    QAction*    openAct;
    bool        crash;
};
```

When running this application in debug build, a click on **File->Open** will call `open()`, where an asertion failure happens. I would expect that program execution stops here. However, it does not.

Indeed, the next paint event is properly processed and function `paintEvent()` is called. (I can be sure that `paintEvent()` is called because an assertion failure in the function pops up a 2nd assertion failure dialog.)

In the end, I get 2 (modal) debugger dialogs showing Abort/retry/Ignore. Only the 2nd dialog is available for interaction. And clicking Abort on this dialog switch the debugger at code line corresponding to the 2nd `assert()` call, in `paintEvent()`.

Enterring the VS debugger at this point shows the following call stack:

```
... c++ runtime code ...
Example.exe!MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * evt) Ligne 37  C++     -> 2nd assertion failure here...
... Qt code ...
[External code] 
Example.exe!MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * evt) Ligne 37  C++     -> ...or maybe here
... Qt code ...
[External code] 
>   Menus Example.exe!MainWindow::open() Ligne 31   C++                         -> 1st assertion failure here
... Qt code ...
Example.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Ligne 10  C++
Example.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * __formal, int __formal) Ligne 111    C++
[External code]
```

My questions are:

- why is my application not aborting at first assertion failure ?
- is there any way to make sure that application will properly abort when first assertion failure happens (in the same situation as the one described above) ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in Release or Debug build?

Comment: @drescherjm I get 2 debugger dialogs : one for the 1st assertion and a seconde one for the 2nd assertion (both are standard debugger dialogs with Abort/Retry/Ignore buttons)

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I mean 2 modal dialogs, and interaction available with the 2nd one only, which "Abort" button starts the debugger on the 2nd `assert()`

Comment: Could be related to being inside a pant event.

Answer (score 0):

An `assert(..)` statement should only be used for checking conditions in debug builds. It should never be used for avoiding problems in release builds because asserts are not executed in release builds.

In Visual C++, `assert(..)` only generates code for **DEBUG** builds. It does nothing in Release builds. From the documentation [of assert(..) on Microsoft's site:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/c-cpp-assertions?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Assertions_in_Debug_and_Release_builds)

> Assertion statements compile only if _DEBUG is defined. Otherwise, the compiler treats assertions as null statements. Therefore, assertion statements impose no overhead or performance cost in your final Release program, and allow you to avoid using #ifdef directives.

Qt also supports its own cross platform version of asserts: `Q_ASSERT(..)`, `Q_ASSERT_X(..)`, and `Q_CHECK_PTR(..)`. Like the plain `assert(..)` these also only work in Debug builds.

> Q_ASSERT(), Q_ASSERT_X(), and Q_CHECK_PTR() expand to nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG is defined during compilation. For this reason, the arguments to these macro should not have any side-effects. Here is an incorrect usage of Q_CHECK_PTR():

Personally, if I am developing in Qt, I stay in Qt and don't mix things. Therefore, I prefer to use Q_ASSERT instead.

Comment: Thanks jwernerny but I know what `assert()`is for. In this situation, I use it for debugging my application and, in this situation, it perfectly did the job, showing me a bug in my program. My problem is that I expect my program to abort on such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

> why is my application not aborting at first assertion failure ?

Because you didn't ask it to. Maybe you want to set a breakpoint later and allow the program to continue. Maybe you know that this assertion is harmless in this particular case and wish to ignore it.

Until the decision to abort is made, no attempt to abort the entire process is made. The thread that called `assert` just runs the `assert` code until a decision to abort is made.

> is there any way to make sure that application will properly abort when first assertion failure happens (in the same situation as the one described above) ?

If `assert` doesn't do exactly what you want, make your own macro that does whatever it is that you want to do. If you want to immediately forcefully abort the process, you can do that.

Comment: Assertion fails, so I expect that a debugger dialog pops up and ask me if I want to abort or not; which should at least suspend the execution. This does not happen and execution continues until a second assertion failure happens, and at this point the 2 expected dialogs pop up.

Comment: @shrike It does suspend execution of the calling thread, but not the entire process. Suspending an entire process is not really a thing.

Comment: The application is single threaded. The call stack clearly shows it: both `assert()` happen in the same call stack. If you have a windows machine available with Qt sdk installed, please try my code by yourself, you'll see.